# Why am I not seeing the printf buffer flush?

Tags: c, output, printf, stdout, execvp

I have a simple program (working example):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  pid_t my_pid = getpid();
  char str[30];

  sprintf(str, "/proc/%d/fd", my_pid);
  printf("hello, I am gonna print out: %s", str);

  execvp( "ls", (char *[]) { "ls", str, NULL } );

  return 0;
}
```

compiled with gcc on a Linux VM. My question is why the output sent to `printf` is never printing.

I understand that `printf` buffers its output and only flushes on `\n`. I am wondering why it is that it doesn't print in this case. I read that output streams are flushed on program exit. `printf` is buffering outputs in a `malloc`'d piece of memory (I confirmed this in my implementation).

My questions about this (more details are welcome):

- Why does commenting out the call to `execvp` cause the output to be printed on `stdout`, but it is not printed as is? My thought is, wouldn't it still be considered program exit even after `ls` cannibalizes the process?
- Would `printf`'s in-memory buffer be considered an output stream?
- A completely unrelated detail to this question is I am wondering why the file descriptor `10` on `zsh` and `255` on `bash` are not inherited by my process.

Comment: Or in other words: the buffered data is stored in memory local to the old process – but as this one is replaced entirely by a new one the former ceases to exist – before it could flush the buffer. The memory of it is either discarded or re-used (overwritten) by the new process.

Comment: "wouldn't it still be considered program exit" No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`execvp` replaces the old process with a new process. Any open file descriptors remain open, but the data buffered by the C stdio library is not preserved. The C startup code will attach a new FILE pointer to the STDOUT file descriptor. The key point is that a **file descriptor** is an OS object, whereas a **`FILE` pointer** is a C library object. Only the OS object is preserved.

Comment: Does a `FILE*` correspond to the buffered memory (as in `printf`)? Why is it necessary to have both a `FILE*` and a file descriptor? If I close file descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO`, should I expect `FILE* stdout` to stop working?